# Deriving Selberg's asymptotic formula from Selberg's identity

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

It is known that

$$
\Lambda(n)\log n+\sum_{d|n}\Lambda(d)\Lambda\left(\frac nd\right)=\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)\log^2\frac nd
$$

summing this on both side gives

$$
\psi(x)\log x+\sum_{n\le x}\Lambda(n)\psi\left(\frac xn\right)=\sum_{d\le x}\mu(d)\sum_{q\le x/d}\log^2q+\mathcal O(x)
$$

It follows from Selberg's asymptotic formula that $RHS=2x\log x+\mathcal O(x)$, so I proceeded with the Mobius inversion identity that

$$
2x\log x=2\sum_{d\le x}\mu(d)\sum_{q\le x/d}{x\over qd}\log{x\over qd}
$$

Plugging this into the RHS, we have

$$
RHS=\sum_{d\le x}\mu(d)\sum_{q\le x/d}\left[\log^2q-{2x\over qd}\log{x\over qd}\right]+2x\log x+\mathcal O(x)
$$

Hence, it remains to show that this gigantic double sum is $\mathcal O(x)$, but this is where I became stuck.

NOTE: I am aware that there is an alternative and much simpler proof of this asymptotic formula, but I want to try and see if the method presented in this post is practicable.